# Drag and drop components in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I apologise if this seems very vague but I'm not sure how else to word it.
I'm new in Visual Studio environment (2015 ) with Xamarin . Many developers have said it is not possible to drag and drop components in Xamarin , that everything should be done in .xaml file. On the website of Xamarin , shows that it is possible to perform drag and drop as the link below:

[Xamarin website](https://www.xamarin.com/platform)

After all , it is possible or not to perform the drag and drop components? If possible, how to do it ?

Comment: The drag/drop IDE UI Designer you are viewing in that Flash animation is for `Xamarin.iOS` and is the iOS StoryBoard/Xib Designer, there is also a `Xamarin.Android` Layout Designer  for creating your *.axml*-based layout files. There is **not** a built-in `Xamarin.Forms` (XAML) drag|drop Designer. There is an alpha version XAML *Previewer* in Xamarin Studio, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.
Xamarin Android and Xamarin iOS have visual designer(drag&drop) in Visual Studio.

It is [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/designer_overview/part_1_-_designer_basics/) for Xamarin Android. 
It is [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/) for Xamarin iOS. 
Xamarin Forms not suppоrt visual designer.